# Batch crop many images to certain ratio

Tags: image-processing, cropping, batch

I have over 2000 picture of various subjects and artworks that I want to crop to certain ratio depending on the closest defined aspect ratio.

The ratios I need are 1:1 and 7:5 and 1:3 They can be both portrait and landscape

Examples,
Original dimensions (px) => Cropped dimensions (px)
100:110 => 100:100
159:50 => 150:50
42:120 => 40:120

How can I do that?
I am in Windows 10

*Bonus point :) I am not sure if this can be done, but if it can do "Smart" cropping and detect the important part of the image that would be great

Comment: Check the `xnview` or `irfanview` utilities.

Comment: I'd probably write my own (Perl?) script for this and make use of [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org)

Comment: @xenoid Tried both but they do not offer this option. Or at least I couldn't find it. Are you sure it is there?

Comment: Let us know your software budget. If you have Adobe Creative suite, you can use Bridge to sort by aspect/orientation, then batch crop.